# using scipy in django with apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, scipy, mod-wsgi

I have defined a django view that uses `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. This works without problems using the django development server, but when I deploy the Django application with Apache and mod_wsgi the view function gets stuck importing curve_fit:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
```

When this line is removed the rest of the app works well on the Apache server. Why does this line not work with Apache and mod_wsgi?

Comment: Does your Apache installation have the `scipy` installed?

Comment: scipy is a python library that is installed in the server using pip

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro pretty sure I know what the issue is, but just in case. On the server have you tried to do a python manage.py shell / shell_plus and import scipy just to verify this is working?

Comment: @JamesR yes, the import scipy works well in the interactive shell

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your WSGI file you will have something that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost>
    ...
    WSGIScriptAlias / /somepath/deployment/wsgi/yoursite.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

You need to add the following line:

```
<VirtualHost>
    ...
    WSGIScriptAlias / /somepath/deployment/wsgi/yoursite.wsgi
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```

The explanation for that can be found here:

http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2011-November/031014.html

Comment: I've spend more than six hours to find your answer. I even actually have written down my own question and by suggested similar question I found yours. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

many thanks for this post. I had the same Problem with spaCy and fixed it by the

```
<VirtualHost>
    …

    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```